# How to correct a iteration on a Multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have a table "recipientMap". This table looks like that :

```
| MapID | IPgroupID | PCgroupID | AlertID
|:------|----------:|:---------:|:------:
|   1   |     1     |     1     |   15
|   2   |     3     |    null   |   15
|   3   |     3     |    null   |   16
```

This table helps me to know who can access to a message.

This choice is done when a user write the alert from the Mvc application, with a checkbox list for each. So I built an array for checked IP group id's and for checked PC group id's and push both into a new multidimensional array. I send this array to the controller. Next step is to iterate on it, and built a list based on RecipientMap model.

The problem is when one of the list has more or less checked id. For example, If I have in my multidimensional array a result like that :

```
list[0][0]=1
list[0][1]=3
list[1][0]=1
```

I get an error because there is no `list[1][1]`. My list must have the same length... it's not good, and I know it's because my iteration method is not correct, I need some advice to correct it.

`List[0][x]` is for IP and `List[1][x]` is for PC. My array could have one or both list.

```
$('#bttn').click(function () {
    var brutelistip = null;
    brutelistip = [];

    var brutelistpc = null;
    brutelistpc = [];

    $('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-1 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        brutelistip.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    $('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-2 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        brutelistpc.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    var recipientlist = new Array();
    recipientlist[0] = brutelistip;
    recipientlist[1] = brutelistpc;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Panels/CreateNewAlert',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            ...
            list: recipientlist,
        }),
        async: false,
        processData: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

And the controller :

```
public JsonResult CreateNewAlert(AlertMap alertMap, AlertLog alertLog, RecipientMap recipientMap, int[][] list)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...

        var RM = new RecipientMap();
        List<RecipientMap>reciplist = new List<RecipientMap>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            reciplist.Add(new RecipientMap
            {
                IPgroupID = list[0][i],
                PCgroupID = list[1][i]
            });
        }

        AL.RecipientMap.AddRange(reciplist);
        AL.AlertMap.Add(AM);
        db.AlertLog.Add(AL);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Reason Object Oriented Programming was developed, was to avoid multi dimensional arrays. There is no need to use array indexes here, you can create JSON array and send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both `list[0]` and `list[1]` are the same length, then it may be wise to replace `list.Length` with `list[0].Length`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Length; i++)
{
    reciplist.Add(new RecipientMap
    {
        IPgroupID = list[0][i],
        PCgroupID = list[1][i]
    });
}
```

If they're not the same length, you're going to have to do a conditional check before accessing one or the other. Either solution is a bit fiddly but they both work for their different circumstances.

Where one exists but the other does not, you could insert a `null` into one of the `RecipientMap` properties to create the `List<RecipientMap>` element.. or you could not create it at all. It's entirely up to your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I found a solution ! First of all I wish to keep [0] for ip list and [1] for pc list. So I'v added a if statement, for push 0 if there is no checked item.

```
    if ($('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-1 input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
    {
        $('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-1 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            brutelistip.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
    } else {
        brutelistip.push(0);
    }

    if ($('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-2 input:checkbox:checked').length > 0)
    {
        $('#AlertCreationTabs #AlertCreationTabs-2 input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            brutelistpc.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });
    } else {
        brutelistpc.push(0);
    }
```

And then in the controller

```
if (list[0][0]!=0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Length; i++)
    {
        reciplist.Add(new RecipientMap
        {
            IPgroupID = list[0][i],
        });
    }
}

if (list[1][0]!=0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list[1].Length; j++)
    {
        reciplist.Add(new RecipientMap
        {
            PCgroupID = list[1][j],
        });
    }
}
```

I know that repeting code is not a very good practice, but... it's enough for the moment.

Comment: Well done :) @mrplume Sometimes things aren't that efficient, but they work.